# Livewire add an quantity input for each row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am trying to add a product to my cart from a list of products. I am using Laravel Livewire. With the code below I am managing to add each product where I click order to the cart (which is just a session variable). Now, I am trying to add an quantity input so that for each product I can choose an amount of products to add to my cart.

Bear in mind from my code below that `Products` is an eloquent collection and in that collection I don't have a property quantity. To my opinion this is also not needed as the quantity is not part of the product model but rather something that belongs to my cart.

So below is my the Livewire php part.

```
class Dashboard extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public string $search = '';

    public function render(): View 
    {
        return view('welcome', [
            'products' => Product::search('description', $this->search)->paginate(9)
        ])->layout('layouts.app');
    }

    public function addToCart(int $productId)
    {
        Cart::add(Product::where('id', $productId)->first());
    }

}
```

And this is the blade part:

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
    <x-table.row wire:loading.class.delay="opacity-50" wire:key="{{ $product->id }}"> 
      <x-table.cell>{{ $product->description }}</x-table.cell>
      <x-table.cell> &euro;{{ number_format($product->price, 2) }}</x-table.cell>
       <x-table.cell> 
        <input type="number"name="quanity" class="w-16 mx-8" />
          <button wire:click="addToCart({{$product->id}})">Order</button>
       </x-table.cell>
      </x-table.row>
 @endforeach
```

I would think the best option is to add a second parameter to the `addToCart` function which is the quantity. But I can't make that work.

Suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be you need to set up an array in your livewire class for your quantities, maybe with the product id as the array key, quantity as the value, and `wire:model` bind your `quantity` input field to this array. I don't have time right now to play with this, but I think it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might suffice

```
public function addToCart(int $productId, int $quantity)
    {
        Cart::add(Product::where('id', $productId)->first()->setAttribute('quantity',  $quantity));
    }
```